# How can I convert a file Uri scheme into content Uri scheme?

Tags: android

In android, when you get the uri from the gallery, it's value will be start with `content://blahblahblah.blahblah.format`, but if you get the uri from your phone's camera, it will be starting with `file:///`

Below is what I want to do:

```
private File uriToBitmap(Uri uri, int maxSize) throws FileNotFoundException {
  try {
        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap claimBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
   }
```

In this method I would like to pass a file type uri and use getContentResolver() function, but unfortunately the claimBitmap is a `null`, does that means the getContentResolver() method doens't accept the file type uri? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, file scheme is supported by ContentResolver, if the uri which scheme is not support, this method will throw a FileNotFoundException. Please check the

```
public final InputStream openInputStream(Uri uri)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
    String scheme = uri.getScheme();
    if (SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE.equals(scheme)) {
        // Note: left here to avoid breaking compatibility.  May be removed
        // with sufficient testing.
        OpenResourceIdResult r = getResourceId(uri);
        try {
            InputStream stream = r.r.openRawResource(r.id);
            return stream;
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException ex) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource does not exist: " + uri);
        }
    } else if (SCHEME_FILE.equals(scheme)) {
        // Note: left here to avoid breaking compatibility.  May be removed
        // with sufficient testing.
        return new FileInputStream(uri.getPath());
    } else {
        AssetFileDescriptor fd = openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r", null);
        try {
            return fd != null ? fd.createInputStream() : null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Unable to create stream");
        }
    }
}
```

this is the source code of ContentResolver, hope this can help you

Comment: So how can I simply just convert the file uri scheme into a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream(android.net.Uri)) . It will helps you
If you stored as in local drive.

```
    String filePath = null;
    Uri _uri = data.getData();
    Log.d("","URI = "+_uri);
    if(_uri!=null&&"content".equals(_uri.getScheme())){
    Cursor cursor=this.getContentResolver().query(_uri,new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA},null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    filePath=cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();
    }else
    {
    filePath=_uri.getPath();
    }
```

Comment: this should be a comment